# No me aclaro con los loops for en Python

Tags: python

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo a programar en python, y no me acabo de aclarar con los loops:

El ejercicio consiste en recorrer la lista `n` y hacer que la variable result de la función `join_strings` sea esas dos palabras juntas, es decir hacer una concatenación. Pero por muchos ejercicios que haga de bucles `for` no me aclaro como funcionan para los diccionarios y las listas en python

Tengo este código:

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]
# Add your function here

def join_strings(words):
    result = ""
    for word in words:
    result += word
  return result

print join_strings(n)
```

Y en la consola me da este error:
File "python", line 7
    result += word
                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

En la página donde lo estoy aprendiendo hay una opción que te enseña el código pero creo que he hecho lo mismo que el código de la solución pero me da ese error

Muchas gracias.

Comment: En Python los bloques de código se delimitan usando  identación. Simplemente el bloque del `for` no tiene nada dentro lo que ocasiona el error. Identa la línea `result += word` con cuatro espacios y pon el `return` al mismo nivel que la línea `result = ""`.  Por cierto `print("".join(n))`  hace lo mismo pero mucho más eficiente, para el futuro. :) . Usa siempre cuatro espacios por cada nivel de identación, de acuerdo a [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**En Pyhton es muy importante la indentación**, `result += word` debe estar dentro del `for`, y el `return` de la función `join_strings` debe estar al mismo nivel del nombre de la función.

Por ejemplo si1 para que se considere dentro de la función, si lo colocas al nivel de la definición de la función obtendrás que el return esta fuera de la función: "'return' outside function".

El código correcto es:

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]
# Add your function here

def join_strings(words):
    result = ""
    for word in words:
        result += word # ***correcta indentación.
    return result # ***correcta indentación.

print join_strings(n)
```

Realizando los cambios, el resultado sería :

```
MichaelLieberman
```

Comment: Entonces por ejemplo al definir una funcion, lo que está dentro debe estar una tabulación más hacia la derecha que la definición? En tal caso el editor de codeacademy está mal...

Comment: Si, para que se considere dentro de la función, si lo colocas al nivel de la definición de la función obtendrás que el return esta fuera de la función: "'return' outside function".

Comment: @PavloB. cual es la url del editor de codeacademy, para revisar.

Comment: no sabría decirlo ya que no se puede acceder si no estás registrado, la url del ejercicio es esta: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-python/lessons/lists-and-functions/exercises/using-two-lists-as-two-arguments-in-a-function?action=lesson_resume

Comment: @Pawlo creo que el ejercicio en español sin necesidad de registro es https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-hsood/4/1?curriculum_id=53a32847fed2a88075000001. Una cosa que te recomiendo es que aprendas Python 3 y no Python 2, difiere en bastantes cosas y no tiene mucho sentido aprender Python 2 ni desarrollar software con vistas a futuro cuando en 2020 deja de tener soporte, no va a tener actualizaciones mayores (2.7 será la última) y  prácticamente todo el código importante está portado a Python 3. Para empezar te pelearás menos con la codificación ;).

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de Jorgesys es la adecuada, solo voy a agregar algunos conceptos.

Una de las primeras cosas de **Python** que debe llamar la atención a todo programador que viene de otros lenguajes, es el tema de la identación. En la mayoría de los lenguajes que poseen sentencias de comienzo/fin de bloques, las clásicas llaves `{}` de **C** o **Java**, los `BEGIN/END` de **Sql** y etc., la identación suele ser opcional, y se usa simplemente para dar legibilidad al código.

Python no usa sentencias de fin de bloques lógicos (Los `:` marcan el comienzo) ya que usa directamente la identación como forma de estructurar la lógica. Esto al principio puede parecer "raro", pero cuando se "internaliza" este concepto, se transforma en algo totalmente transparente y altamente efectivo a la hora de escribir el código ya que:

- Hay que escribir mucho menos
- La forma de escribir código es más estándar
- El código es más legible

El [metodo oficial](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) para establecer la identación es el de usar bloques de 4 espacios, pero funciona también usar los clásicos `{TABS}`, lo importante es que no se puede mezclar criterios, sino obtendremos un error de ejecución.

Como ya dijimos, todo bloque lógico comienza con los `:` y lo que sigue debe estar identado un nivel más que este, ejemplos:

```
if True:
    print("Es true")

def función():
    pass

class Algo():
    def __init()__:
        pass
```

En tu ejemplo, has escrito: `for word in words:` y la instrucción siguiente no está un nivel más adentro sino que está al mismo nivel, por consiguiente obtienes un `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`. La forma correcta es la siguiente:

```
# Este es tu ejemplo corregido
for word in words:
    result += word
```

También tienes otro error de identación en el `return`, que seguramente generará otra excepción cuando corrijas el primer problema.

**Comentario**: Una duda que puede surgir, es si es posible escribir bloques sin código, lo que sería un `{}` en C, si es posible pero hay que usar la clausula `pass`, por ejemplo:

```
for word in words:
    pass
```

Solo a titulo informativo, con respecto a la lógica de tu función es la adecuada a lo que estás queriendo hacer/investigar, pero en Python siempre hay formas más compactas de resolver algún problema, lo mismo que buscas puedes resolverlo así:

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]
print("".join(n))
```

En este ejemplo usamos el "metodo" `join` de la clase `str` que recibe directamente un objeto "iterable" como una lista o un diccionario y los concatena usando como separador un string "nulo", `""`.

Comment: Estoy planteando en Meta que todas las preguntas de Python muestren una sugerencia para que los usuarios etiqueten de forma más preciso. ¿Podrías darle un vistazo? [¿Podemos añadir una advertencia en las preguntas con etiqueta \[python*\]?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3860/83). Tu opinión sería interesante pues eres de los más reputados en esta etiqueta. ¡Gracias!